# Text File with Matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Desired which I hope to achieve:

```
hello number
A 1 1
B 1 1
```

This is code

```
m2=matrix(1,2,2)
row.names(m2)=c("A","B")
fileConn <- file("name.txt")
  writeLines(c(paste0("hello number"),
  c(paste(m2))), fileConn)
  close(fileConn)
```

But I get

```
hello number
1
1
1
1
```

So I am wondering how I can fix this for desired output? It is possible to do so and have row names for this matrix? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: `write.table(m2,col.names=F)` instead of  pasting `m2` to writeLines

Comment: That does not include the first line "hello numbers"

Comment: you still have to use the old `writeLines`. Just add the `write.table` to the same connection afterwards.

Comment: @Julian_Hn Error in writeLines(paste0("hello number"), write.table(m2, col.names = F),  : 
  'con' is not a connection

Comment: I've added a complete answer, since you seem to need the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add a complete answer here, since the comments only allow oneliners:

```
file <-  "name.txt"
writeLines("hello number",con=file)
write.table(m2,file=file,append=T,col.names=F)
write("goodbye number", file=file,append=T)
```

Comment: I am beginner so thank you and do need some extra help.  May I ask a additional question from just wondering: that is, what if I wanted to add "goodbye number" at the bottom? I try to append but it does not take this command. I am just wondering.

Comment: I've edited in the solution. Use `write()`instead of `writeLines()`